# Starting a 2D Platformer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm starting a 2D platformer in Unity. I want to write it in C#, but most of the tutorials I'm finding are in JavaScript. Is there any good tutorial you can direct me to?

If not, what is a good place to start? I'm new to Unity so I'd like to start by making a ground for the character to walk on in the first level and then a simple character model (no specific design so I don't have to model an actual character at this point) that I can add a script to. How can I go about these simple ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences between C# and Javascript when using Unity3D are not as dramatic as you might think. The Unity3D documentation has a page describing the most important differences (apart from syntax of course):

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Writing_Scripts_in_Csharp_26_Boo.html

Also, the official unity documentation allows you to switch between JavaScript, C# and Boo.

If you want to get started with Unity3D, additionally to the official documentation there are a lot of sites around (just google it), one site that i found quite helpful was [unity3dstudent.com](http://www.unity3dstudent.com), going through at least the [Essential](http://www.unity3dstudent.com/category/modules/essential-skills/) and [Beginner](http://www.unity3dstudent.com/category/modules/beginner/) modules as well as the [Challenges](http://www.unity3dstudent.com/category/challenges/) should help to get a basic understanding of how things work.

Comment: Thanks I will check these links out.